# Not able to impose rules on xPert perturbations

Tags: xact

Whenever I try to define rules to xPert perturbations, they seem not to work at all. For instance, I am interested in considering traceless and divergence-free perturbations and defining

`rule1 = MakeRule[{g[a, b] Perturbation[g[-a, -b], 1], 0}, ContractMetrics -> True]`

`rule2 = MakeRule[{CD[-a]@Perturbation[g[a, b], 1], 0}, ContractMetrics -> True]`

seems to be ignored, as you can see in the example

`Perturbation[RicciScalarCD[], 1] // ExpandPerturbation // ContractMetric // ToCanonical /. rule1 /. rule2`

that gives

[image]

Full code:

```
  Quiet[<< xAct`xTensor`;
   << xAct`xTras`;
   << xAct`xPert`;
   ]];

$DefInfoQ = False;
$PrePrint = ScreenDollarIndices;

DefManifold[M, dim, {a, b, c, d, e, f}];
DefMetric[-1, g[-a, -b], CD, PrintAs -> "g"];
PrintAs[RiemannCD] ^= "R";
PrintAs[RicciCD] ^= "R";
PrintAs[RicciScalarCD] ^= "R";

rule1 = MakeRule[{g[a, b] Perturbation[g[-a, -b], 1], 0}, 
   ContractMetrics -> True];

rule2 = MakeRule[{CD[-a]@Perturbation[g[a, b], 1], 0}, 
   ContractMetrics -> True];

DefMetricPerturbation[g, h, \[CurlyEpsilon]]

Perturbation[RicciScalarCD[], 1] // ExpandPerturbation // 
  ContractMetric // ToCanonical /. rule1 /. rule2
```

Comment: I get an error coming from the definition of `rule1` when I copied and pasted the expression in the OP. Then `rule1` remains undefined

Comment: I realized rule1 was wrong, but rule2 should be fine. What error do you get?

Comment: Now, I am not getting any errors from either of the rules. However, you should note that `RicciScalarCD[]` remains unevaluated. In other words, when I run `Perturbation[RicciScalarCD[], 1] // ExpandPerturbation // 
  ContractMetric // ToCanonical /. rule1 /. rule2` I get the error `ToCanonical::noident: Unknown expression not canonicalized: RicciScalarCD[] .`

Comment: I am not getting that error. Maybe it has something to do with the previous lines of the notebook? I did not put all of them, they are a lot.

Comment: Yes, I know. But if you don't provide your code it's not possible for the other members to test it, right? ;)

Comment: Yes, you're right. I edited the question and add it